# Linear time reduction of languages in class P, complexity implications

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, reduction, np

I am having problem understanding this topic of P and NP reductions. I understand that if language L1 can be reduced to Language L2 in linear time and L2 is in P, this implies that L1 is in P. But if we know L2 has a time complexity of lets say theta(n log n), can we say that L1 runs in O(n log n)? since the reduction from L1 to L2 is in linear time and L2 runs in theta(n log n) and so it will be O(n) + theta(n log n). And also lets say L2 can be also linearly reduced to L3, we can say L3 runs in omega(n log n)?

Comment: Can you improve the title a bit? i couldn't come up with a good idea, but something along the lines of "reduction of language, complexity implications". Just so people who search for something like this can find it easier..

Comment: I edited my answer. You might want to have a look at it again. I hope things are clearer now and I apologize for the confusion...

Comment: I changed the title. Your answer is better now and its clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Yes. And yes in case you mean big Omega.

---

The first part is correct: If you can decide L2 in Theta((n*log(n))) which implies it can be done in O(n*log(n)) and you can reduce L1 to L2 in O(n), then you can also decide for L1 in O(n*log(n)) with exactly the argument you made. (Note: this does *not* mean, that you can't possibly decide L1 in less than this - there might be an algorithm to solve L1 in O(n). It's only an upper bound...)

<s>However, the second part is not correct. If you can reduce L2 to L3, then you can say nothing about L3s running time not matter what the running time of the reduction from L2 to L3 is.</s> (Update: this only shows that L3 might be harder, not more) L3 might be a very hard problem, like SAT for instance. It then is very likely that you can reduce L2 to it, i.e. that you can solve L2 with 'rephrasing' (a reduction) the problem + a SAT-solver - still SAT is NP-complete.

---

DISCLAIMER: as noted in the comments by DavidRicherby the second part of my answer is wrong as it stands - @ uchman21 you were right, L3 has to be in Omega(n*log(n)) (note the upper case!):

If we know the complexity of L2 is Theata(n*log(n)) (upper and lower bounds, O(n*log(n)) *and* Omega(n*log(n))) and we can reduce L2 to L3 in time O(n), then L3 is at least as hard as L2 - because we know there is *no algorithm* which can solve the problem L2 faster than Omega(n*log(n)). However, if L3 was faster, that is in o(n*log(n)), then the algorithm 'reduction+solve_L3' runs in O(n)+o(n*log(n)) which still is in o(n*log(n)) and it solves L2 - contradiction. Hence, L3 has to be in Omega(n*log(n)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i understand it better.

Comment: "If you can reduce L2 to L3, then you can say nothing about L3s running time not matter what the running time of the reduction from L2 to L3 is." That is not correct. If you can reduce L2 to L3, you know that the complexity of deciding L3 is at least as big as the complexity of deciding L2. Note that the claimed bound on L3's complexity is an Omega (lower) bound, not an O (upper) bound.

Comment: @DavidRicherby omg.... You are right! My mistake, I will edit as soon as I get to a pc..

Comment: @DavidRicherby you are right.. so L3 will have a complexity of omega(n log n) right?

Comment: @DavidRicherby : can you please check if I got it right this time? Would be great! Many thx..

Comment: Looks good now, yes. One thing to note is that you're implicitly using the fact that the question restricts to linear-time reductions. In general, if the reduction takes time f(n), then the output of that reduction might have length f(n), so determining if that is in L3 would take time f(n)log(f(n)). Here, there's no problem because f(n)=n, but things would be more complicated if we were talking about, say, polynomial-time reductions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Thank you very much for the feedback. Actually, I wanted to write a generalized answer with f(n) instead of fixed running times, but I noticed that I was getting on thin ice because I couldn't really figure out what it means for L3 if the reduction takes as long or longer than L2s running time itself.... so I thought I'll stick to the question, there I was at least somewhat sure that it should work...

Comment: @DavidRicherby : I thought that if reducing takes longer, then it might be that L3 is easier than L2 - we kind of "pre-work" the problem. For instance if the reduction is "solving the problem itself" and the algo for L3 simply outputs "true" if the input starts with "true" and it returns "false" otherwise. L3 runs in constant time and the "reduction" is basically deciding L2, i.e. the reduction solves L2 and outputs "true" or gibberish otherwise. Then actually L2 would be harder than L3. What am I missing? I guess my confusion comes from the fact that all this is in P anyway, so who cares :)

Comment: You're not missing anything. If you have a problem in TIME[f(n)] and you allow yourself time g(n) = Omega(f(n)) to do a reduction, then you can solve the problem in the reduction and just reduce to true/false, as you say.